# What is this dishwasher drain solenoid seal part & how can I replace it?

Tags: dishwasher

Our dishwasher (GE GSD3200G00WW) is leaking underneath whenever the drain process kicks in.  It looks like the seal between the [drain solenoid](http://www.partselect.com/PS260117-GE-WD21X10060-Drain-Solenoid-Kit.htm?SourceCode=1&SearchTerm=GSD3200G00WW&ModelNum=GSD3200G00WW) and the drain itself has deteriorated and should be replaced.

Removed the drain solenoid:

[image]

This part (1/2 inch in diameter) (that is right against the drain around where the shaft comes out) popped right off:

[image]

And behind it you can see rotted rubber type material inset into the drain itself around the shaft:

[image]

which is almost certainly where the water is coming out.

In the videos I can find showing how to replace the drain solenoid, it shows this part already being in place, as if built into the drain itself, for example in this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZX9uP8UcPc#t=96 :

[image]

So -- what is this part called?  And, how can I replace it?  Can I just scrape out the remaining rubber from the drain around the shaft, and then pop the new part in?  Or is this so integrated with the drain that I'll need to fully remove the drain and pump and everything?

Comment: Have you seen the water coming from this location? If not, start a cycle and watch. Because there is a hose nearby, this is a more likely culprit in an aging machine...I once had a Kenmore of similar vintage and from which I extracted a few more years of life by repairing a similar drain cycle issue.

Comment: Yes, I did see water come out of it, not the hose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is a shaft seal (the links below), you might want to get the push-on nut also (GE part number [AP2059046](http://www.appliancepartspros.com/ge-push-on-nut-wr2x7054-ap2059046.html)), as you may have to cut it off to install the seal.

---

[searspartsdirect.com](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/partsdirect/part-number/GE-Parts/Dishwasher-Parts/WD08X0181/0022/363/Model-GSD2030F00WW/0432/0130000?keySuffixId=&pathTaken=partSearch&pathRender=modelComponent&documentCompId=G0040235&diagramPageId=00003&productTypeId=&searchModelNumber=GSD2030F00WW&subCompDesc=Motor-pump%20mechanism&brandDesc=GE&modelDesc=DISHWASHER&blt=11&shdMod=&keyId=417), Part number: WD08X0181, Substitution: WD8X181. (Part may differ in appearance but is a functional equivalent)

[appliancepartspros.com](http://www.appliancepartspros.com/ge-seal-wd8x181-ap2038837.html) also shows this seal as: Part Number WD8X181